# Java: wait to receive a value from another server (by http?)

Tags: java, http, struts2, client-server, httpclient

I am developing a web application with struts2&spring3 and one of the last things I need to do is the communication between my server and another server where I have to send a XML file and after wait for its response.

As someone said me, I have implemented the sending of the XML file by HTTP with the library HttpClient4 (from Apache):

```
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(file, "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(server);
        method.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
```

But now I have to implement the **waiting and getting of the response that the other server will send me**. The problem is that the other server is still not developed, so, which way you think it would be the best to get that answer? by HTTP also would be perfect but I don't know which library and how to do it.

Thank you very much in advance for all your help,

Aleix

Answer (score 1):

Here I find two options

1. Send response immediately.
2. Develop a module [client side] which accepts response from server after request is received and added to queue [ Asynchronous mode ]

Comment: The problem is that the server where I send the XML file will have to parse that file and do some calculations, and after will send me a response that would be a String. So he can not send me the response immediately (the first option you said). Please, can you explain me better or with some link about the second option? Thank you very much;)

Comment: @Aleix, Second option is also a simple solution, you need to develop a servlet or similar to handle the response your server.  Example: support http://myserver.com/app/receiveResponse.jsp will be page to receive all responses from your server2. In this way you can receive response even after long duration.

Comment: sorry but I don't get what you mean... for sure it is my fault because I am a bit new in all these. What I was thinking is in some Java code in the same action, after sending the XML file, like `while(not_received){ask_for_the_response;}`, so that I am able to return the response value from that action, sorry if it is so abstract description... any idea? or can you try to explain me your idea in another way? any example maybe? Thank you really very very much;)

Comment: as you might be aware of Asynchronous processing. Processing requests in queue will also lead to asynchronous response i.e delayed response. For this write a JSP or Servlet which recieves xml and deploy it in server1 [Which sends request to server2 ], Response from server2 will be automatically received by server1 provided you handle requests properly at server2